# Show ActivityIndicator over current rendered component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that determines which component to return when a user opens the application based on authentication status.

```
class MyApp extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.authenticated) {
      return <AuthenticationContainer />
    }
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor={this.props.online ? Colors.blue : Colors.gray} />
        <Navigation />
        <FirebaseController />
        <PushNotificationController />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

When the user is authenticated it returns a few different components wrapped in a single view. The Navigation component holds a DrawerNavigator from `react-navigation` that is basically the entire application. I also have a couple "controllers" returned alongside the Navigation component that I register some listeners on componentDidMount() but return null in their render function. In the FirebaseController component, I sometimes have some logic running in the background. During this time, I set a state variable `loading` to true, and set it back to false after the logic completes.

**My question**: Is there a way to render an ActivityIndicator over top the Navigation component while `this.state.loading` inside FirebaseController is true? I have tried setting the render inside the controller to

```
render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator style={{ zIndex: 1 }} />
    }
    return null
  }
```

and some other variations, but without success. I'm not entirely certain this is even possible.

Comment: ActivityIndicator expects a `animating` prop to show. Did you use it?

Comment: The default is true and I have not set it to false

Comment: Did you try wrapping it with a View and setting style's position prop to absolute?

Comment: I swear I tried this and many other ways and now it is working. Wrapped it in a view and set position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center'. Thanks, feel free to post as answer

Comment: Its ok. Even a typo might cause a problem. glad that its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to wrap the `<ActivityIndicator/>` (or whatever you want to return) in a `View` and set the style of the view to `style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, justifyContent: 'center' }}`.